# How to select fairseq option `--ddp-backend`

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, distributed-computing, fairseq

I'm learning how to use [`fairseq`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq) to implement a simple translation model based on Transformer.

I would like to use 2 GeForce RTX 3090 GPUs on my lab server. Which option should I select for `--ddp-backend` of `fairseq-train`?

Furthermore, could you explain about the meaning of all following options for `--ddp-backend` and when to use them respectively?

> From [`fairseq` Documentation: Command-line Tools => `fairseq-train` => distributed_training](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line_tools.html#distributed_training)
>
> ---
>
> `--ddp-backend`:
>
> Possible choices: c10d, fully_sharded, legacy_ddp, no_c10d, pytorch_ddp, slowmo
>
> DistributedDataParallel backend
>
> Default: “pytorch_ddp”

I'm new to stack exchange community, sorry if there is any inappropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure, but I found this on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/blob/main/fairseq/dataclass/constants.py)

```
DDP_BACKEND_CHOICES = ChoiceEnum(
    [
        "c10d",  # alias for pytorch_ddp
        "fully_sharded",  # FullyShardedDataParallel from fairscale
        "legacy_ddp",
        "no_c10d",  # alias for legacy_ddp
        "pytorch_ddp",
        "slowmo",
    ]
)
```

Might be helpful, but I am also struggling with this

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the options.py file, hope it's helpful. But they only describe the difference between "c10d" and "no_c10d". So we should keep going to find more.

This is the [link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/commit/704922869536d658a4981e108a4e33bf47a8b531).